# Laravel multiple sql select to AS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to select multiple database columns and to merge them to an AS value statement like `SELECT sum1 as vsd FROM tablename WHERE year = 2017`

I have multiple columns I need to output as one value. So I imagine the above code looking something like this:

`SELECT (sum1, sum2) as vsd FROM tablename WHERE year = 2017`

My current live-code query looks like this:

```
$query = DB::table('exports')->select('id', 'year', 'week', 'month', 'staff_a, staff_b as vsd')->having('year','=',$year)->where('week', '<=', $weeknr)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(14)->get()->reverse();
```

The result is:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'staff_a, staff_b'
>   in 'field list'

I tried to combine them (columns) to an array (`array('staff_a', 'staff_b')`), had some weird foreach-loops and whatnot trying to make it work another way but all that threw yet another error message.

Is there any way to "merge" multiple selects to one?

Comment: `(sum1, sum2) as vsd` this is not merging even in mysql. How do you want to merge them ? by adding both columns sum1 + sum2 as vsd?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Yes, they should be added together, simple math if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use RAW syntax:

```
->select(DB::raw('staff_a + staff_b as vsd'))
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: Unfortunately, that only uses the last column (staff_b) as vsd and outputs the first column as staff_a.

Comment: @Andreas see the update one this should do what you want

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid That did it. Thanks!